# DateTime.Compare doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm trying to compare two DateTime objects ignoring the seconds with the below function, but it gives the wrong result even though both of the DateTime objects are have the same values. Can't figure out how to exactly get it working, any help would be highly appreciated.

```
public static int CompareDateTime(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    d1 = d1.AddSeconds(-1 * d1.Second);
    d2 = d2.AddSeconds(-1 * d2.Second);

    int result = DateTime.Compare(d1, d2);
    string relationship;

    if (result < 0)
        relationship = "is earlier than";
    else if (result == 0)
        relationship = "is the same time as";
    else
        relationship = "is later than";

    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", d1, relationship, d2);

    return result;

}
```

Result:

```
3/7/2017 2:54:00 PM is later than 3/7/2017 2:54:00 PM
```

Comment: What are the milliseconds?

Comment: Where did `d1` and `d2` come from? Could be that their milliseconds / ticks under the hood are slightly different. Were they created with two `DateTime.Now` calls?

Comment: Just because you remove full seconds, does not mean they have different milliseconds...

Comment: You're doing something wrong.  Here's what I get: `03/07/2017 14:54:00 is the same time as 03/07/2017 14:54:00`

Comment: best way to truncate to minutes is `new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day, d.Hour, d.Minute, 0);`

Comment: refer to the doc, but the comparison take the ticks into accounts, not the seconds only. Oh and also, the `Kind` of the 2 `DateTime`s. So, given your output in full seconds, times could be equals, different, not comparable, ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem here is that you aren't truncating as you expect to. The best way to truncate is to create an entirely new DateTime object from the constructor by doing the following:

```
d1 = new DateTime(d1.Year, d1.Month, d1.Day, d1.Hour, d1.Minute, 0);
d2 = new DateTime(d2.Year, d2.Month, d2.Day, d2.Hour, d2.Minute, 0);
```

This will ensure you are only comparing the data you want.

In this specific case it is the milliseconds that may have been part of the datetime that were being left by your attempted truncation.

Comment: As regards milliseconds... In a case I experienced, I ensured that the milliseconds were the same but then the Ticks still caused the two dates I was working with to not be equal. I had to do a truncation like you did in your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to ignore the milliseconds as well. You could add this to your code, or go for the more 'elegant' solution suggested by @Chris

```
d1 = d1.AddMilliseconds(-1 * d1.Millisecond);
d2 = d2.AddMilliseconds(-1 * d2.Millisecond);
```

Answer (score 3):

Everyone is giving a solution for truncating time... So I'll give the one that I normally use... A `DateTime` is the number of ticks starting from 0:00:00 on January 1, 0001... so if you know how many ticks there are in a minute (there is a readonly field for that: `TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute`) you can count the number of minutes from January 1, 0001...

```
long minutes1 = d1.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute;
long minutes2 = d2.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute;

int result = minutes1.CompareTo(minutes2);
```

(note that there are various "useful" values in `TimeSpan`: `TicksPerDay`, `TicksPerHour`, `TicksPerMinute`, `TicksPerSecond`, `TicksPerMillisecond`)